# Help implementing page caching in Rails 3 app served from a subdirectory via Passenger/Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am serving a Rails 3 application from a subdirectory with Passenger and Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RackBaseURI /streamspons
  <Directory /var/www/html/streamspons>
     AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews 
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In my controller I cache a page:

```
caches_page :banner
```

When the #banner action is called, the page is written out to public/, but *inside of another directory named for the app's subdirectory* (in other words, the entire request string including the subdirectory is in the cache path):

```
Started GET "/streamspons/decks/2/banner.js"
...
Write page /var/www/public/apps/streamspons/releases/20110316162902/public/streamspons/decks/2/banner.js
```

When this action is requested again, it misses the cache and runs the action again because the cached page should be at `public/decks/2/banner.js` instead of `public/streamspons/decks/2/banner.js`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I wound up caching the page by hand at the end of the action: `cache_page response.body, "/decks/#{params[:id]}/banner.js"`. Feels hackish, but works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 3.0.1 I added this to my app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...

  # override this class method to strip the path to the
  # rails app root from the request path
  def self.page_cache_path(path)
    path.gsub!(%r[^/streamspons], "")
    page_cache_directory + page_cache_file(path)
  end
end
```

In latest Rails this might look like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...

  def self.page_cache_path(path, extension = nil)
    path.gsub!(%r[^/streamspons], "")
    page_cache_directory + page_cache_file(path, extension)
  end
end
```